# promtail: transform the whole log line based on regex

Tags: grafana-loki, promtail

I'm having some challenges with coercing my log lines in a certain format.

I'm running one `promtail` instance on several log files, of which some are `logfmt` and others are free-form.

My objective is to transform the free-form ones to the same `logfmt` as the others, independent of any other labeling. That means the actual payload (*log line*) pushed to my `qryn` instance is then supposed to have the same format, and I woudn't even be able to "see" the original, free-form log line downstream. This should enable me to use a simple `| logfmt` in `grafana`, regardless of the log source.

I tried in several ways, but I can't get the log line replaced, i.e. while I can extract to labels in all ways conceivable, I can't **replace** the actual log line.

A (slightly redacted) `promtail-config.yml`:

```
server:
  disable: true

positions:
  filename: ${RUNDIR}/.logs/positions.yaml

clients:
  - url: http://mylocalqryn:33100/loki/api/v1/push
    batchwait: 5s
    timeout: 30s

scrape_configs:

- job_name: consolidated-logs

  # https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/clients/promtail/pipelines/
  # https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/clients/promtail/stages/template/
  pipeline_stages:
  - match:
      selector: '{ Program="freeformlog" }'
      stages:
      - regex:
          expression: '^(?P<time>^[0-9-:TZ.+]*)\s+(?P<level>[A-z]*)\s+(?P<Function>[0-9A-z:.]*)\s+(?P<msg>.*$)'
      - timestamp:
          format: RFC3339
          source: time
      - template:
          source: level
          template: '{{ ToLower .Value }}'
      - labels:
          level:
          msg:
          Function:
      - replace:
          expression: '.*'
          replace: 'time="{{ .timestamp }}" level="{{ .level }}" msg="{{ .msg }}" Host="{{ .Host }}" Program="{{ .Program }}" Function="{{ .Function }}"'

  static_configs:
  - targets:
    - localhost
    labels:
      Host: ${HOST:-"_host-unknown_"}
      Program: logfmtcompat
      __path__: ${RUNDIR}/.logs/logfmtcompat.log
  - targets:
    - localhost
    labels:
      Host: ${HOST:-"_host-unknown_"}
      Program: freeformlog
      __path__: ${RUNDIR}/.logs/freeformlog.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled on the same problem. It seems that replace only replaces things on captured regexp groups, not matched ones. The solution for your case is:

```
      - replace:
          expression: '(.*)'
```